# JavaScript Array verification and finding the last item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a function that accepts an array and returns the last item in the array.

```
let test=["hichem","amine", 2 , 5];

function getLastItem(arr) {

    if (arr.isArray ===true) {

         return console.log(arr[arr.lenghth-1]);

    }

    return console.log("The entered data is not an Array");

}

getLastItem(test);
```

I write this code and I get this message in the console:

> Failed to load resource: **net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

instead of the result

Comment: Your code has typo. Used `lenghth`

Comment: Why are you returning `console.log()`? Isn't it strange? lots of errors too...

Comment: Except all the mentioned typos in your code, can you show how are including the file??

Comment: FYI: `isArray` is a **_static_** method and should be called as `Array.isArray`

Comment: I'm learning JS it's kind of practise exercise

Comment: Array.isArray(arr)===true You have to do this

Comment: Actually `net::` errors have no relation to JS (apart from AJAX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function getLastItem() {
  var arr=["hichem","amine", 2 , 5];
  if (arr instanceof Array){
     return arr[arr.length-1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return the last item if it's an array or give a console log statement if it's not.

You have used the wrong syntax. 
It is Array.isArray(arr).

```
let test=["hichem","amine", 2 , 5];

function getLastItem(arr) {
 if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
  return (arr[arr.length-1]);
 }
 return "The entered data is not an Array";
}

console.log(getLastItem(test));
```

Comment: It can be just written `Array.isArray(arr)`.

Comment: It'd be better to move `console.log` out of the function and wrap the function's result. Currently this code doesn't output anything if the function receives an array.

Comment: @hindmost Thanks for the suggestion! Now the answer will give output

Answer (score 0):

All is good in your function but "arr.isArray ===true" this line is not working. it should be something like below code. But i don't know why you are returning console.log from a function. but if you want forcefully there is nothing wrong just modify your code.

```
let test=["hichem","amine", 2 , 5];
    function getLastItem(arr) {
        var isArray=(arr instanceof Array); //or test.constructor === Array
        if (isArray) {
             return (arr[arr.length-1]);
        }
   return console.log("The entered data is not an Array");
}
getLastItem(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

- arr.isArray is undefine, you can coding like this:

```js
let test=["hichem","amine", 2 , 5];

function getLastItem(arr) {

    if (arr instanceof Array) {

         return console.log(arr[arr.lenghth-1]);

    }

    return console.log("The entered data is not an Array");

}

getLastItem(test);
```